# Custom post type 'orderby' => 'meta_value' not working

Tags: custom-post-types, sort

I have a custom post type called Member I have added code to my functions.php file to add a couple of custom column headings (which is working) for First and Last name and Member Type but I can't get the default post_title column to sort from A-Z. I'm sure it has something to do with title vs post_title or something but this is new to me. What am I doing wrong?

```
/*add custom columns to the member post type*/
add_filter( 'manage_edit-member_columns', 'my_edit_member_columns' );

function my_edit_member_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns = array(
        'cb' => '<input type="checkbox" />',
        'title' => __( 'Member' ),
        'first_name' => __( 'First' ),
        'last_name' => __( 'Last' ),
        'member_type' => __( 'Member Type' ),
        'date' => __( 'Date' )
    );

    return $columns;
}

/*add hooks to add content to the columns*/
add_action( 'manage_member_posts_custom_column', 'my_manage_member_columns', 10, 2 );

function my_manage_member_columns( $column, $post_id ) {
    global $post;

    switch( $column ) {

        /* If displaying the 'first name' column. */
        case 'first_name' :

            /* Get the post meta. */
            $first_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'first_name', true );

            /* If no first_name is found, output a default message. */
            if ( empty( $first_name ) )
                echo ( 'Unknown' );
            else
                printf( $first_name );
            break;

        /* If displaying the 'last_name' column. */
        case 'last_name' :

            /* Get the post meta. */
            $last_name = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_name', true );

            /* If no first_name is found, output a default message. */
            if ( empty( $last_name ) )
                echo ( 'Unknown' );
            else
                printf( $last_name );
            break;

        /* If displaying the 'member_type' column. */
        case 'member_type' :

            /* Get the post meta. */
            $member_type = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'member_type', true );

            /* If no first_name is found, output a default message. */
            if ( empty( $member_type ) )
                echo ( 'Unknown' );
            else
                printf( $member_type );
            break;
        /* Just break out of the switch statement for everything else. */
        default :
            break;
    }
}

//make the title sortable
add_filter( 'manage_edit-member_sortable_columns', 'my_member_sortable_columns' );

function my_member_sortable_columns( $columns ) {

    $columns['post_title'] = 'post_title';

    return $columns;
}

// now do the sorting of the member post type
// Only run our customization on the 'edit.php' page in the admin.
add_action( 'load-edit.php', 'my_edit_member_load' );

function my_edit_member_load() {
    add_filter( 'request', 'my_sort_member' );
}

/* Sorts the member. */
function my_sort_member( $vars ) {

    /* Check if we're viewing the 'member' post type. */
    if ( isset( $vars['post_type'] ) && 'member' == $vars['post_type'] ) {

        /* Check if 'orderby' is set to 'title'. */
        if ( isset( $vars['orderby'] ) && 'post_title' == $vars['orderby'] ) {

            /* Merge the query vars with our custom variables. */
            $vars = array_merge(
                $vars,
                array(
                    'meta_key' => 'post_title',
                    'orderby' => 'meta_value', /*use meta_value_num if the meta_key is numeric*/
                    'order' => 'asc'
                )
            );
        }
    }

    return $vars;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The post's title isn't meta data, it's in the main post table. You can order by title with:

```
'orderby' => 'title'
```

You would specify a meta key / order by meta value if the field were custom data stored in the post meta table.

Comment: Ok so I modified the code to this.

`array(
     'post_type' => 'member',
     'orderby' => 'title', 
     'order' => 'ASC'
    )`

but it still is sorting by the newest post date and not by the title.